# iOS cancel touch events in certain regions

Tags: ios, uitouch

Is there a way to cancel touch events in certain regions of a view? I have a custom UIView and I only want to process touch events only if they are say 100 pixels from the edges of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justin said, add a custom UIView in interface builder (or programmatically) and add it to the view. let's call that view touchArea. Then in your Viewcontroller.m file, implement the

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

methods (depends on what you're trying to do), and in these do:

```
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchArea.frame, location)) {

//code to execute

}
```

actually, I think even a CGRect as an instance variable that is placed on the view can work, but the above is how I achieved it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Interface Builder, simply take another UIView. Resize it, and place it where you want touch events to occur. Then, have the custom view able to be touch active. Programmatically, I, personally, do not know how to do it.